# How do you create a dynamic excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking at creating an Excel chart that offers some interactivity. Basically, at the moment I have a chart that is detailing progress (in %) using bars. But that progress is usually made up of several other aspects. So you could have an overall progress of say 50% which would then be broken down into;

1. Graphics 75%
2. Sound 25%
3. Gameplay 50%

Now what I'd like to do is find a way to stack those bars, so that I have the bar showing the overall progress and only when I click on that bar the other, more detailed progress bars appear.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. There might be a workaround using pivot tables, pivots charts, and slicers, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not stated what version of Excel you are using, and I don't have an exact answer for what you are trying to do, but I do know with some work you can achieve some nice dynamic charts in Excel 2007 and later.

[Chandoo.org](http://www.chandoo.org) has some great tutorials on charting. One specifically is [How to create an Interactive Chart in Excel? [Tutorial]](http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/04/23/interactive-chart-in-excel-tutorial/) may be what you're looking for.